# Why is my sound so low?

Tags: sound

I thought I fixed my low-sound-issue after I edited `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and added

```
options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0
```

I did a reboot and now my sound is low again. All settings are at max...

Comment: Do you Beats Audio per chance?

Comment: Do I Beats Audio? What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

> Hi there.
>
> I've got the same Problem with my Asus Z97 Deluxe and the ALC1150
>   Audio Controller. In search for a solution i found this thread and
>   added to my
>
> `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
>
> as follows "options
>
> `snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0"`
>
> If that not works and you
>   have a  ALC883 or similar soundchip you may need to add to your
>
> `/etc/modules`  to `"snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0"`
>
> After that reboot. It works fine with my board and i'm happy to hear
>   my music in fine quality.
>
> Best regards Elrico

It's from here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181764&p=2

Seems like a few people who had your problem solved it with this.

Comment: When I added "options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0" to **/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf** it helped the first time I had this problem. After I did a reboot the sound was low. I also tried to add it to **/etc/modules** now but with same result... Audio still low...

Comment: morgan@morgan:~$ aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution for this. Just power off the computer completely and restart it. Sound back to normal!

Comment: Is "normal" the originally low volume or the tweaked-up volume?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use pavucontrol to change the output level:

[image: use pavucontrol to set output gain]